# NavigationBar and StatusBar not fully transparent on some devices

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar, navigationbar

I'm writing an application using react-native, and I'm trying to show content behind status and navigation bars. I managed to solve this issue by adding some code `styles.xml`. This managed to solve my issue, but I recently realized that It doesn't fully work on all devices. On my `Pixel 6` running `Android 12` the status and navigation bars are not fully transparent.

[Transparent status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2qpn.png)

I tried many things that got suggested on Stack Overflow, but none of them fully worked. I even managed to get it working on a native android app, but writing the same code in a react-native app doesn't work.

This is the code that I currently have in my `styles.xml`:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:enforceStatusBarContrast"  tools:targetApi="q">true</item>
    <item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast"  tools:targetApi="q">true</item>
```

Comment: Remove the first two lines. Translucent means half transparent, the color is controlled by system and it overrides your other attributes. Read more here: [Display content edge-to-edge in your app](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge)

Comment: Thank you! You are right, the first 2 lines are unnecessary, but this did not fix the issue. I went through the article you sent before posting it, but reading through it one more time made me realize what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. As Eugen Pechance pointed out, the first two lines of my original `styles.xml` are unnecessary. However, the main thing causing the half-transparent background were `android:enforceStatusBarContrast` and `android:enforceNavigationBarContrast` lines. The way that android enforces the contras is by adding that semi-transparent background to the status and navigation bar, which is not the way I thought it works. Setting these values to `false` does the trick.

Also, according to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge) article you should add the following line to the `MainActivity.java` get the content to go behind the status and navigation views:

```java
@Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
```

Make sure that you override the correct `onCreate` function, since the default overriden function in react native doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in `MainActivity.java` inside the `onCreate()` the following code:

```
Window w = getWindow();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

And on the `themes.xml` file make sure the parent is **NOT** any DarkActionBar! for example:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

and then add:

```
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- Navigation Bar color. -->
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@android:color/transparent</item>
```